# Not getting description when using action property

Tags: python

Part of my python code

```
(operation == 'checkstatus')
checkStatusParser = subparsers.add_parser(operation, prog = operation, add_help = False)
        group = checkStatusParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
        group.add_argument('-d', dest = 'applicationName', nargs='?', default='',const=' ', help = 'Application deployment name')
        group.add_argument('-m', dest = 'machineName', nargs='?', default='', const=' ', help = 'Machine name' )
        checkStatusParser.add_argument('-i', required = False, dest = 'instanceName', help = 'Instance name')
        checkStatusParser.add_argument('-an', required = False, dest = 'agentName', help = 'Agent name')
        checkStatusParser.add_argument('-da', required = False, dest = 'displayAll', action='store_true', help = 'Display all')
        checkStatusParser.set_defaults(func = checkStatus)
        subparsersList.append(checkStatusParser)
```

When I run like

```
python applicationsMgmt.py checkstatus
```

I get below :

```
usage: checkstatus (-d [APPLICATIONNAME] | -m [MACHINENAME]) [-i INSTANCENAME]
               [-an AGENTNAME] [-da]
checkstatus: error: one of the arguments -d -m is required
```

The problem here is I do not get descrition of `-da` option as I get for other variables like for `-d` I get `[APPLICATIONNAME]`

Answer (score 0):

The `-d [APPLICATIONNAME]` denotes that user should write an argument after the -d option. Option `-da` doesn't follow up with an argument, so there's no `[DISPLAYALL]` shown in usage.

Comment: So how can I display the same?  Any Idea?

Comment: Would you like `-da` to take one argument after it or no arguments at all? If you advertise to user that it takes one when in fact it doesn't you'll confuse your user.